# Why is there not a destructive version of `to_s`?

Tags: ruby, string

Lets say:

```
n = 5
n.to_s
p n
```

the result of `n` is still `5` rather than `"5"`. What's the shortest way to replace the original variable `n` with my newly converted `n` without having to go through the following:

```
n = 5
a = n.to_s
p a
```

Why doesn't Ruby allow me to call `to_s!` on the object?

Comment: The shortest I know of are `n=n.to_s` or `n="#{n}"`, but both require an assignment of the string back to the variable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An integer cannot magically turn itself into a String. Methods (including `!` methods) can only cause the object value to change, not the type. Besides, integers are immutable -- the integer itself can't be modified (but the name pointing at it can be re-pointed at a new integer).

Therefore, `to_s!` does not exist, and instead you need to rebind the variable by writing e.g.

```
n = n.to_s
```

Comment: Your intent is correct, but the description regarding `!` is not correct. `!` does not necessarily mean a destructive methods. It is OP's mistake though.

Comment: @sawa: slightly reworded, better?